# How soon are windows performance counters available?

Tags: performance

I can't get performance counters on a restarted Windows 7 computer, from a remote computer, until 1min-2min after I login. Is there something that I can do to make this available faster? I use the following code:

```
PDH_STATUS  status;
HQUERY        perfQuery = NULL;
HCOUNTER    uptimeCounter;
char        uptimeCounterPath[] = "\\\\SRVJET01\\System\\System Up Time";
PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE uptimeValue;
DWORD seconds = 0;
if( PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, perfQuery ) != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    return FALSE;

status = PdhAddCounter(perfQuery, uptimeCounterPath,0, &uptimeCounter );
if( status != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    return FALSE;

status = PdhCollectQueryData( perfQuery );
if( status != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    return FALSE;

status = PdhGetFormattedCounterValue( uptimeCounter, PDH_FMT_LARGE , NULL, &uptimeValue );
if( status != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    return FALSE;

PdhCloseQuery( &perfQuery );

seconds = (DWORD) (uptimeValue.largeValue);
```